# Using Selenium webdriver on a custom webkit browser

Tags: selenium, webkit, selenium-webdriver, qtwebkit

I have successfully tested applications in FireFox using Selenium WebDriver, but one of our applications runs in a custom browser made using QTWebKit. Is it possible to use WebDriver to automate testing in a custom browser like this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a webdriver for QtWebkit here: https://github.com/cisco-open-source/qtwebdriver

It also can automate qtwidget and QML aplications.

You should be able to use it to automate you custom browser, provided you preserved the QtWebkit APIs.

Answer (score 1):

If QTWebKit has released a WebDriver executable for the browser, then yes.

Otherwise - no.